# Positioning issues in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, position

I've made a theme for the blogging platform Tumblr, and it works fine on all browsers except IE.

IE won't fix the position of a div on the bottom of the screen, and squishes everything to the left instead of most of them being fixed to the right.

The address is 009panelstheme.tumblr.com

Here's a screenshot in IE: http://i56.tinypic.com/2b30jk.png

Same thing in Chrome: http://i55.tinypic.com/2d8172o.png

I've tried the whole Doctype thing, and I found someone who said to add this line:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
@media screen {
* html {overflow-y: hidden;}
* html body {height: 100%; overflow: auto;}
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

But nothing I do works.

Any suggestions would be wonderful. Thank you so much.

Comment: If you want help, you should copy your code to http://jsfiddle.net so that we can play with it easily.  Otherwise it's too hard for us to figure out your problem.

Comment: [validate, validate, validate](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2F009panelstheme.tumblr.com&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt at adding a doctype failed. Using IE's Developer Tools (press F12), you can clearly see it's rendering in Quirks Mode. Changing it to Standards Mode in the Developer Tools makes it work.

When I look at the source, I see this:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control" content="off"/><!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
...
```

The [doctype](http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/) needs to be the very first thing on the page!

Where does that `meta` tag come from? Can you move it into the `head`?

Speaking of which, further down the page I see this:

```
<header>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    ...
```

`header` isn't what you should be using there. It's `head`. [`header` is something else entirely.](http://html5doctor.com/the-header-element/)

Comment: awesome answer for crappy attempt at HTML.